# Does 'async' have any benefit for TypeScript functions that already return a Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Is there any reason to mark a TypeScript function as `async` if the return type is already a promise? My understanding is that `async` automatically wraps the return in a promise, so these are essentially identical:

```
function foo(): Promise<Bar> {
}

//vs

async function foo(): Bar {
}

//Or even

async function foo(): Promise<Bar> {
}
```

I suppose some IDEs might have better support for type checking with one or the other, but that would be a quirk of that program rather than the TypeScript language.

Comment: `async function foo(): Bar` cannot exist - TS mandates that async functions return `Promise`. So, you only have first and third available.

Comment: Related: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-function-return-type-promise

Comment: You only need `async` if you're going to `await` it. Also note you can't have `async` functions on _types_, _only_ functions that return promises (because it's not relevant to their type whether or not they're implemented with `async`).

Comment: This is not specific to TS. It works just the same as in JavaScript, so the reasons are the same.

Comment: Would always use `async` in a function that returns a promise. If your code throws before it returns the `Promise` from a non async function, that error would simply be thrown (synchronously) from calling that function, it wouldn't be caught by the promise. (`@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `async` without returning a `Promise`.

And you can't `await` in a function that is not `async`.

And the difference IF you target below ES2017 :

```
type Bar = {};

function foo(): Promise<Bar> {
}

async function foo3(): Promise<Bar> {
}
```

Generated JS:

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
function foo() {
}
//Or even
function foo3() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    });
}
```

Comment: @VLAZ My bad, Fixed what I meant.

Comment: You can also use `await` at the top level in modules...